# How to exclude object property

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, orika

I using Orika mapper to map two beans. i would like to exclude billingSummary.billableItems property while mapping. I am trying below option but it is not working.

Any help?

```
public class Cart {
       private String id;
       private String name;
       private BillingSummary billingSummary;
       private String address;
       //with getter and setter methods
    }

   public class BillingSummary {
       private String billingItem;
       private String billingItemId;
       private BillableItems billableItems;
       ...
       // with getter setter methods
   }

   //FilteredCart is same as Cart.


 public class FilteredCart { 
        private String id;
        private String name;
        private BillingSummary billingSummary;
        private String address;
        //with getter and setter methods
    } 

@Component   
public class CartMapper extends ConfigurableMapper {
        @Override
        public void configure(MapperFactory mapperFactory) {
        mapperFactory.classMap(Cart.class,FilteredCart.class).exclude("billingSummary.billableItems").byDefault().register();
        }
}
```

Comment: Is it correct `billableItems` in the mapping exclude? From your code, I can see `billingItems`

Comment: I have corrected it.  I forgot to keep it in the initial request.  Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is adding another mapping to the `mapperFactory` in order to define how you want to map the `BillingSummary` to itself. In this way, when mapping from `Cart` to `FilteredCart`, you can configure to exclude to map the `billableItems`.

Therefore, your `CartMapper` will look like this:

```
@Component   
public class CartMapper extends ConfigurableMapper {

    @Override
    public void configure(MapperFactory mapperFactory) {
        mapperFactory.classMap(BillingSummary.class, BillingSummary.class).exclude("billableItems").byDefault().register();
        mapperFactory.classMap(Cart.class,FilteredCart.class).byDefault().register();
    }
}
```